# submit button doesn't close the form

Tags: form, submit

I have a sharepoint list which was working fine up to now.

Now the problem is that the submit button in the 'new' form submits data in the list but  **does not**  closes the form. Actually when user presses submit button, nothing happens to user. It remains in the form.

I checked the button's submit options and 'after submit' action is set to 'close the form'.

There's a log in my server logs which says:
*'an event log to be applied against a form was invalid Request:ABC Source:XYZ...'* where ABC and XYZ are related to my list.  What does this log mean?

Any hints are really appreciated.

Comment: Check if there is a javascript error - in the case you dont know: press f12 to open the developer tools and then check the console.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sitting inside a form web part? If so, there is another option in web part settings to close the form.

You can also try giving the button rules instead, and using a submit action followed by a close form action (this assumes you are using infopath to customize the form).

Comment: The form is in a 'InfpPath form webpart'. There's a 'Allow close'  checkbox in its settings and its checked. And there's not any action related to closing the form in actions that I have here. Thank you for your response

Comment: There is a "Select the action" on the form webpart (http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-help/use-the-infopath-form-web-part-HA102770988.aspx), and also inside infopath, you can add rules to the button instead of making it submit directly. You can add a submit action and then a close the form action straight after. I have done this recently with success.

Comment: The actions you are after are "Submit Data" and "Close the Form." http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/infopath-help/add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-HA101783373.aspx

Comment: I don't see 'close the form' action in infopath. But there's an 'after submit action' in webpart settings. I set it to 'Close the form' but the result was not acceptable:It replaces the form with the message: “The Form Has Been Closed”. But I want the user to redirect user to the list itself (the behavior was like this before)

Comment: Do you have any idea why I see 'submit data' and not 'Close the form'?

Comment: Do you have a Form Library or are you customising a custom list?

Comment: It's a usual list and the problem is in the form used for adding new items.